# What does the word 「ごねだした」 mean?

Tags: words, manga

I'm not sure if it is a nuance of the word 「ごねる」 which means to make difficulties or to grumble.

Here is the sentence containing the word.

> なんせ... 青山が五人の選手の中に入れてくれって**ごねだした**のは知ってるんだ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ごね出した【だした】 means "started to grumble." 出す is one of the syntactic compound verb elements. After the masu-stem of a verb, it means "to begin to ～", similarly to ～始める. See: [What is the difference between 出す and 始める when used as a suffix?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11711/5010)